# Vector of virtual class in C++

Tags: inheritance, virtual

I'm learning C++ and reading a book, A tour of C++.

In section 9.2.1, this book says

```
vector<Shape> vs;               # is bad, 
vector<Shape*> vps;             # is better, and
vector<unique_ptr<Shape>> vups; # is OK.
```

My question is why "vector<Shape> vs;" is not accepted, and  "vector<unique_ptr<Shape>> vups;" is best? Could you clarify it?

Shape class here is a virtual class. In a previous chapter, Circle class and Triangle class had been defined as derived from Shape. Circle class object and Triangle class object are intended to be stored in the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vector` container owns every object in it, specifically constructing the object to become part of the vector. Since you cannot construct a `Shape` to go into the vector, there would be no way to use `std::vector<Shape>`. Try to insert an object into that vector, it cannot be done.

On the other hand, a pointer to an instance of any class derived from `Shape` can be converted to a `Shape*`, and you can copy pointers with no problem. So this is fine:

```
vector<Shape*> vps;
vps.insert(new Circle());
```

Similarly, `unique_ptr`s are polymorphic. So you can construct a `unique_ptr<Shape>` that points to an instance of a class derived from `Shape`.

But there is no way you can make a `Shape` that is an instance of a class derived from `Shape`. So `vector<Shape>` is a non-starter.

Another way to see it is to look at what space the vector will allocate. For a vector of `Shape*`, it will allocate enough space to hold a `Shape*`, and that can hold a pointer to an instance of a class derived from `Shape`, no problem.

For a vector of `unique_ptr<Shape>`, that will allocate enough space to hold a `unique_ptr<Shape>`, and that can hold a unique pointer to a `Shape` that points to a class derived from `Shape`, no problem.

But what happens with `vector<Shape>`. That allocates enough space to hold a `Shape`. But what can we do with that if we're trying to store a class derived from `Shape`? There is nothing at all we can do with that space! Instances of derived classes are typically larger than instances of their base classes, so such a vector would again be useless to us.